# React Native Cannot Resolve Module

Tags: react-native

I'm building a react-native app that's IOS only and I keep getting the following error:

`node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js cannot resolve module DrawerLayoutAndroid`

I see the component in the node_modules folder so I'm not sure why this would be missing. Also if I comment out the line that includes that module then the file fails on a different module. Thanks for any feedback or ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using RN v0.44.2, check this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14209 Lot of people are facing similar issues. Downgrading to v0.44.1 seems to solve this issue.

Comment: This was exactly the problem! Thanks!